# Use a passed id from parent view to fetch and display detail view - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I made a list with a navigation view and I'm passing the ID to a detailed view but I need to fetch more data from a different endpoint to get more data in the detail view. Unfortunately, I got stuck to update the ObservableObject to load the detailed data for one post.
Where and how should I set the postID in order to fetch detailed data ?

```swift
// PostsListView
struct PostsListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var obs = postsObserver()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView(){
                VStack{
                    ForEach(obs.posts, id: \.name) {post in
                        NavigationLink(destination: PostView(postId: post.id)){
                            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                Text(post.name)
                            }
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }.padding(.horizontal)
            }.id(UUID().uuidString)
        }
    }
}
class postsObserver: ObservableObject{
    @Published var posts = [Post]()

    init() {
        AF.request("http://localhost/posts").responseData{(data) in
            let json = try! JSON(data: data.data!)
            for i in json {
                self.posts.append(
                    Post(
                        id: i.1["id"].intValue,
                        name: i.1["name"].stringValue,
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

// PostView.swift
struct PostView: View {
    @State var postId: Int
    @ObservedObject var obs = postObserver()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(obs.specificValue)")
            Text("\(postId)")
        }
    }
}

class postObserver: ObservableObject{
 //   @Published var post = Post
 //   AF.request("http://localhost/posts/\(postId)/details").responseData{(data) in
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in init, like below

```
struct PostView: View {
    private let postId: Int      // << not state needed
    @ObservedObject var obs: postObserver   // << declare

    init(postId: Int) {
       self.postId = postId
       self.obs = postObserver(postId: postId)  // << initialize
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if obs.specificValue != nil {      // wait till fetch
                Text("\(obs.specificValue!)") 
            }
            Text("\(postId)")
        }
    }
}

class postObserver: ObservableObject{
    @Published var specificValue: ValueType?

    init(postId: Int} {
       AF.request("http://localhost/posts/\(postId)/details").responseData{(data) in
             ... decoding code here

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.specificValue = ...
           }
       }
    }
```